# Can TensoFlow learn unstructured data?

Tags: mobile, machine-learning, tensorflow, voice-recognition

I'm new to TensoFlow and I'd like to know if it is possible to make a tensor flow algorithm do a deep learning in a website or in a database, for instance.
I wish to make and App for iOS using an API, witch someone can ask something about a course in a university for instance and the software would be able to answer.
Thanks!

Comment: You can do mining for voice data by applying  deep learning concept with help of Tensorflow, CUDA toolkit and cuDNN .

Answer (score 3):

First of all Tenserflow is not an algorithm , it is  an open source software library for machine learning in various kinds of perceptual and language understanding tasks. 
I think you can refer the algorithms that are used in chatbots developed by the team of Google i.e. 'Google Brain' . You can refer to this link (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq/) . I know I did not provide you the complete answer but you can take it as a start for your task .

Answer (score 0):

Well, tensorflow is a framework which you can use to develop algorithms as well as to make your computations easier.SO it's in your hand, you can develop anything out of it. And yes if you develop your model with mobile support in mind you can run the trained model in your mobile device.